# Angular-ChartJS align legend right center

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alignment, chart.js, legend

I'm using the Angular-ChartJs wrapper to create a doughnut chart. I'm able to align the legend at the right top using this options:

```
legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'right',
    fullWidth:true
}
```

On the left image you can see how it is and on the right picture you can see how it should be. (the right image is not totally correct aligned but you get what I mean)

[image] [image]

Is there a way to create a custom legend with the data of the chart and align that legend 'right center' to the chart?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/395 and also this https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/45

Comment: yes but for any reason the on 'create' is not triggered. Maybe in angular-chartjs 1.1.1 the chart creation is triggered in another way.

Comment: Any soulution you found for same?

Comment: no just a small hack which is not working in chrome, but barely in firefox. Nothing which will work generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 'options['legendCallback']'

1. I pass the chart options to the canvas using the element attribute 'chart-options="$ctrl.options"'
2. disable legend in chart options '$ctrl.options['legend']['enabled'] = false'
3. create your own legend using '$ctrl.options['legendCallback']'

Example:

```
$ctrl.options['legendCallback'] = function(chart) {
    const text = []
    text.push('<div class="rr-doughnut-chart-legend">')
    // use dynamic legend id to handle multiple charts at once on one page
    text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">')

    // INSERT YOUR CUSTOM LEGEND HERE (perhaps generated automatically with chart object)

    text.push('</ul>')
    text.push('</div>')

    return text.join('')
}
```